# How to filter select options by file type with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a folder on the server with several different file types, and the only ones I want to appear in the `<select>` list as options are the `.json` files. Currently all the files are displaying as `<options>`. I've only seen solutions for `<input>` elements, but not for a `<select>`. How can I display only the `.json` files in the folder? Here is my  element:

```
<form action="/server/php/data/process.php" method="post">
     <select type="text" name="selectTemplate" onchange="loadTemplate()">
           <option value="" selected="selected">Select Template</option>
                    <?php
                         foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/server/php/data/*') as $filename){
                         $filename = basename($filename);
                         echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
                      }
                    ?>
      </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/server/php/data/*') as $filename){
```

like this:

```
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/server/php/data/*.json') as $filename){
```